# Geometry Nodes: Why Does "Combine XYZ" Node ignore my Scene Unit System?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I've learned that certain Geometry Nodes default to metric, even if you have your scene set to imperial.

Is there a way to get around this, or am I forced to think in metric when using Geometry Nodes?

EG:

[image]

[image]

Comment: For some nodes you at least have to think in metric in the sense of using a conversion factor. You probably know that you can enter the imperial value and multiply or divide it by a conversion factor, e.g., enter the X axis dimension using inches: 50*.0254, or 50/39.37.

Comment: Hi @curious_1 thanks for weighing in, and yeah I know I can throw a math node in front of the Combine XYZ to convert metric to imperial, but when you've got a lot of geometry manipulation, especially considering every time you have to split it three ways into x,y,z, your node tree can start to get ridiculously cluttered.  I was hoping there was a way to hijack the system and force all geonodes to respect the Scene Units.  I'm sure there is a good reason, from a programming perspective, but for an end user this is an appalling 'quirk' to have to deal with.

Comment: Agreed.. it's odd, IMO, that the fields are not in Blender Units, however they are configured in the Scene > Units panel.. they shouldn't be bound to metres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone else comes across this question, the answer is:

There is no way around this.  If you are trying to work in imperial units, for certain nodes, the only option is to use a math node to convert metric to imperial.

I hope this will be addressed someday, but as of now (version 3.6) this is how it is.